# Coral SOM Datasheet V1.8 Issue

Tags: google-coral

I am building a carrier board for the Google Coral SOM Module.   Looking at the datasheet [Version 1.8](https://coral.ai/docs/som/datasheet/#digital-audio-sai), it shows that SAI1_RXD7 and SAI1_RXC are both tied to J1312 pin 23.   I wondering if this correct since RXD7 has a pull down resistor, and RXC is clock.

Table 15:
SAI1_RXD7   Input   J1312   23  3.3 V   Receive channel.
Pull-down in SoM: 10k Ohm.
Reserved during boot, except in eFUSE mode. See note above

Table 16:
SAI2_RXC    Input   J1312   23  3.3 V   Receive bit clock

Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks

Don

PS - If google looking at this. the PDF download link in the datasheet points to V1.7 of the datasheet, NOT V1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Coral Baseboard Rev1.3 schematic, it shows that the SAI2_RXC goes to J1322 - PIN 22 and SAI1_RXD7 goes to J1322 - PIN 23.   So Google has a mistake on the schematic.  Time for V1.9